# Sizing the .Rectangular IOS Lock Screen widget

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, ios17

I have the following code for a Lock Screen widget. I see a gap on the left and right side of the widget, as such my content does not fit well. How would I modify it to ensure the entire space of the rectangular widget is used on any iPhone?

```swift
struct RectangularWidgetView: View {
    var entry: WorldClockProvider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(entry.cities.prefix(3), id: \.name) { city in
                HStack {
                    Text(getCityAbbreviation(for: city.name))
                        .font(.system(size:11))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text(getTime(for: city.timeZone, date: entry.date))
                        .font(.system(size: 09))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)  // Set fixed width and right-align the text
                
                }
            
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .widgetAccentable()
    }
}
```

Tried changing the spacer but that did not work

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .padding() modifier or set padding parameters.
See : [Apple Developer Padding Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/padding(_:_:))

Comment: Although this is not (technically) a so-called "link-only answer" (those get deleted through flagging and review queues), it isn't much more than a link. Maybe give a short code snippet as an example of your proposed solution?